# How to pass query result to visualisation URL in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm trying to display an image in grafana based on query result. Is there a way to set the query result (a string) in grafana as a variable, and then add this variable to an URL?

I'm using the AJAX panel, tried saving the variable to "$m" with the "ALIAS BY" field in the Query tab and in the "URL" field of the visualisation tab, I have http://example.com/$m. But this doesn't seem to work.